# Solr dismax: How to specify a field to make a search with the parameter 'qs'?

Tags: php, solr, lucene, solarium, dismax

I would to ask if someone knows how to specify a field using 'qs' parameter. I mean, for example, a have a document with this fields and content

- id: 1
- name: Football
- keywords: football, goal, goalkeeper
- phrase_keywords: premier league, champions league, golden awards,

Then i make a search by: 'premier awards' using Dismax with parameter qs: 20. So, parameters will be like:

```
defType:q=foo&defType=dismax&q:"premier awards"&qs:20
```

Results will be "name" content, right, but i just apply qs:20 to field **phrase keywords**, because if a search: 'goal league' is doenst match any result, although if i break the search in: "goal premier" OR goal OR premier.

Because i would like to search like this:

```
phrase_keywords:"goal premier" or keywords:goal OR keywords:premier
```

but in phrase_keywords with "qs" (proximity) and for keyword a normal search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you couldn't specify field in **qs** param. Usually **qs** param is using with **qf** param, which means query fields.

For more info on DisMax parser syntax - take a look here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser

About this query

> phrase_keywords:"goal premier" or keywords:goal OR keywords:premier

I guess you could achieve it by combining several queries

Comment: Thank you! Well, i dont like much to make a large (with more OR) query, but for now, that query works for me:

`phrase_keywords:"goal premier"~20 or keywords:goal OR keywords:premier` and with boost because phrase_keywords are more specific, will be: `phrase_keywords:"goal premier"~20^10 or keywords:goal OR keywords:premier`